# need help to select month in gmail account with imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

To create gmail account with imacros i have completed everything but getting problem only with month, i have tried a lots but can not select month with imacros.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBoDI.jpg

The codes for the month are as:

```html
<div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" aria-haspopup="true" role="listbox">
  <div id=":1" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="option" class="goog-menuitem"><div class="goog-menuitem-content">January</div></div>
  <div id=":2" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="option" class="goog-menuitem"><div class="goog-menuitem-content">February</div></div>
```

I have tried the following code:

```html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ROLE:listbox CONTENT=#3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:July CONTENT=#3
```

It is clicking on the month button but not selecting any month.

Could anyone help me to sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
SET monthNum 7
SET monthSlc EVAL("var s = '{{monthNum}}'; switch ('{{monthNum}}') {case '10': s = 'a'; break; case '11': s = 'b'; break; case '12': s = 'c'; break;} '#\\\\:' + s + '>DIV';")
SET listSlc "#BirthMonth>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR={{listSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR={{listSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR={{monthSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR={{monthSlc}} BUTTON=0
```

---

By analogy with the 'Month' field, try to set the gender in this way:

```
' e - Female, f - Male, g - Other
SET gender f
SET genderSlc #\:{{gender}}>DIV
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#Gender>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR={{genderSlc}} BUTTON=0
```

Comment: Awesome, i searched 100 page online, nothing worked, but you are the best, it really worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, i need another help with gender selection, i have tried but could not sort out the gender. Could you please help about that?

Comment: Excellent work, everything is working fine, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If normal recording fails, experimental fails try XPATH http://wiki.imacros.net/XPATH .

Use addons for XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to this the current way to do this since the gmail account form has changed since 3 years ago. The image I have attached is dated 11/1/2018. The gender and the month are still dropdowns just like it's shown in the question by OP's image. The following code works with the gmail form I pulled up today:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:gender CONTENT=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:month CONTENT=3
```

The #3 for CONTENT is just the option number to select. You can change that accordingly.

Hope it helps others looking for a current answer.

[image: 11/1/2018 creating google account]