# Select Month/Gender in Gmail account creation with imacros

Tags: imacros

Trying to automate gmail account creation using iMacros. Facing problem in selecting Gender and Month.

Tried [StackOverFlowSolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098572/need-help-to-select-month-in-gmail-account-with-imacros/32113358#32113358) but it is not working for me. It reports that the command not found. Is it some version mismatch issue or am I missing something?

Can anybody help me in resolving this?

Pasted below the recording along with this fix for reference.

```js
VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?dsh=447577167596141020&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount#FirstName=&LastName=
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:PasswdAgain CONTENT=asdf123
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:BirthDay CONTENT=15
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:birthyear-placeholder
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:BirthYear CONTENT=1989
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEL FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:RecoveryPhoneNumber CONTENT=+919791151088
SET monthNum 7
SET monthSlc EVAL("var s = '{{monthNum}}'; switch ('{{monthNum}}') {case '10': s = 'a'; break; case '11': s = 'b'; break; case '12': s = 'c'; break;} '#\\\\:' + s + '>DIV';")
SET listSlc "#BirthMonth>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR={{listSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR={{listSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR={{monthSlc}} BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR={{monthSlc}} BUTTON=0
```

Comment: The solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098572/need-help-to-select-month-in-gmail-account-with-imacros) works in 'iMacros' for **Firefox**. For **Chrome** browser one has to search another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely do this with imacros. Just a small workaround for this.

Below is the code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=ID:HiddenBirthMonth CONTENT=05
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=ID:HiddenGender CONTENT=MALE
```

You can change the above Hidden Input Field's value, and the Month and Gender will get updated (though it might not be visible for the user)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and actually they seem use div and not a select to do it.
The change is probably triggered by javascript. But I thing it would be a waste to time trying to go through their's.

I just saw that the month change the attribute aria-posinset="6". Here it is for June. I don't think that you can change one with iMacros.

Comment: Can the same be achieved using selenium idea?

Answer (score 0):

For the current form, dated 11/1/2018. I did the following and it worked to populate gender and month:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:gender CONTENT=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:month CONTENT=3
```

The #3 for CONTENT is just the option number to select. You can change that accordingly.

[image: 11/1/2018 creating google account]